lightning-record-picker search logic
I am using the new lightning-record-picker in LWC that should display 2 pickers.
One for City__c and one for Street__c, where proposed streets are only streets linked to the selected city.
The search seams to be based on the Name and it is working but for some reasons, for the City it not working where there are blank space in the name. For example for the city 'aa bb' if I search 'aa' I will see the city in the dropdown but when i add the blank space 'aa ' I don't see anything.
It is very strange because for the Street it is working very well, even if there are blank space in the name of the street.
if someone has any idea it, I will be grateful.
HTML:
<template>

<lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" vertical-align="center" class="slds-align_absolute-center">
    <lightning-layout-item size="12" vertical-align="center">
        <div class="slds-p-left_small">
            <lightning-record-picker label="Ciry" object-api-name="City__c" required="true"
            onchange={handleChangeCity} filter={filterCity} value={city}   >
        </lightning-record-picker>
        </div>
       
    </lightning-layout-item>

    <template if:true={cityIsNull}>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12" vertical-align="center">
            <div class="slds-p-top_medium slds-p-left_small">
                <lightning-record-picker label="Street" object-api-name="Street__c"
                    onchange={handleChangeStreet} filter={streetFilter} onsearch={handleSearch}
                    disabled={isStreetDisabled}>
                </lightning-record-picker>
            </div>

        </lightning-layout-item>
    </template>

    <template if:false={cityIsNull}>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12" vertical-align="center">
            <div class="slds-p-top_medium slds-p-left_small">
                <lightning-record-picker  label="Street" object-api-name="Street__c"
                    onchange={handleChangeStreet} filter={streetFilter} value={street} onsearch={handleSearch}>
                </lightning-record-picker>
            </div>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </template>

</lightning-layout>

JS:
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { FlowAttributeChangeEvent } from 'lightning/flowSupport';
import labelCity from '@salesforce/label/c.City';
import labelStreet from '@salesforce/label/c.Street';

export default class GenAddress extends LightningElement {

    label = {
        city: labelCity,
        street: labelStreet
    };


    @api cityId;
    @api streetId;

    @track city;
    @track street;

    @api selectedCity;
    @api selectedStreet;

    @track cityIsNull = false;
    @track isStreetDisabled = true;

    @track streetFilter = {
        criteria: [],
        orderBy: [
            {
                fieldName: 'Name', // Change 'Name' to the field you want to sort by
                order: 'ASC'
            }
        ]
    };

    @track filter = {
        criteria: [],
        orderBy: [
            {
                fieldName: 'Name', // Change 'Name' to the field you want to sort by
                order: 'ASC'
            }
        ]
    };





    connectedCallback() {
        this.city = this.cityId;
        this.street = this.streetId;
        this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('selectedCity', this.city));
        this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('selectedStreet', this.street));
    }

    handleChangeCity(event) {

       
        this.city = event.detail.recordId;
        this.cityIsNull = true;
        if (this.city != null && this.city != undefined) {
            this.street = null;
            this.isStreetDisabled = false;
            this.setStreetFilter();
        }else{
            this.isStreetDisabled = true;
        }
        this.selectedCity = event.detail.recordId;
        this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('selectedCity', this.selectedCity));

    }

    handleChangeStreet(event) {
        console.log('event.detail.recordId', event.detail.recordId);
        this.street = event.detail.recordId;
        
        this.cityIsNull = false;
        
        this.selectedStreet = event.detail.recordId;
        this.dispatchEvent(new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('selectedStreet', this.selectedStreet));

    }


    handleSearch(event) {
        const searchKey = event.detail;

        if (!searchKey) {
            // No search key means no records found
            // You can perform any necessary actions here
            console.log('No records found.');
        }
    }


    setStreetFilter() {
        this.streetFilter = {
            criteria: [
                {
                    fieldPath: 'City__c',
                    operator: 'eq',
                    value: this.city
                }],
            orderBy: [
                {
                    fieldName: 'Name', // Change 'Name' to the field you want to sort by
                    order: 'ASC'
                }
            ]
        };
    }


    setCityFilter() {
        this.filter = {
            criteria: [],
            orderBy: [
                {
                    fieldName: 'Name', // Change 'Name' to the field you want to sort by
                    order: 'ASC'
                }
            ]
        };
    }   

}


The bug is fixed, the issue was not in the component but in the data.
The name of the record included non standard white space, non breaking space so as salesforce mentioned in the documentation, it is not supported as regular white space.
